# Best way to design a modal form in react / ionic

Tags: reactjs, ionic4

I'm learning react so I'm building a weight tracker.
I have different pages where i ask some datas. So i want to develop a modal form.

I have already have a Modal component from Ionic. 
So i builded a ModalForm with an header with close, a cancel and a ok button.
Inside the content i render props.childrens.

Something like that

```
<App>
    <ModalForm>
        <Input>
    </ModalForm>
</App>
```

On pressing "Ok" the component will give the input value to the parent via callback.
That value will be validated ( so i cant give the value onChange).
But it will need to know the values of childrens input.

Moreover the parent will have control of inputs ( and validation ), that is not a thing that i like.

I can let the modal choose what inputs render with an internal switch, but it cant be reused for other porpuse.

Should abandon childrens and found another way ? 
Please give me some advice on how composite my components to achieve this results.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way.

I have a parent component, that is like a wrapper or a decorator, but is lower than my final component.

```
interface ModalProps {
    title: string,
    show: boolean,
    setShow: Function,
    value: number | string,
    onSave: Function
}

const ModalInput: React.FC<ModalProps> = (props) => {
    var { show, setShow, title, value, onSave } = props;
    return (
    <IonPopover isOpen={show}  onDidDismiss={() => { setShow(false); }}>
        <IonContent class="ion-text-center modal-content">
            <IonCard>
                <IonCardHeader>
                    <IonCardTitle>{title}</IonCardTitle>
                </IonCardHeader>
                <IonCardContent className="text-center">
                    {props.children}
                </IonCardContent>
            </IonCard>
            <IonFooter>
                <IonButton color="light" onClick={() => { setShow(false); }}>Cancel</IonButton>
                <IonButton color="primary" onClick={() => { onSave(value); setShow(false); }}><IonIcon slot="start" icon={save} /> Save</IonButton>
            </IonFooter>

        </IonContent>
    </IonPopover>
);
};
export default ModalInput;
```

It tooks the props to open/close the modal, a title, one props to get the child value and onSave that is a callback from app.
Then i wrote a more higher component with the implementation of the children.
All the props goes to the ModalInput wrapper.

```
interface InputProps {
    onSave: Function,
    show: boolean,
    setShow: Function,
    defaultValue: number
}
const WeightInput: React.FC<InputProps> = ({show, setShow, defaultValue, onSave}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(defaultValue);

    return (
    <ModalInput show={show} setShow={setShow} title="Starting weight" value={value} onSave={onSave}>
        <IonItem>
            <IonInput value={value} onIonChange={e => setValue(parseFloat(e.detail.value!))}></IonInput>
        </IonItem>
    </ModalInput>
);
}
export default WeightInput;
```

And finally how to use it :

```
<WeightInput show={showWeight} setShow={setShowWeight} defaultValue={weight} onSave={(w:number) => setWeight(w)}/>
```

So it works like that :

- on input change, the input call setValue for changing the state
- on state change will change also the props for the modal component
- on OK click the modal component will trigger the onSave props, that come directly from the app

So the app should care only about value and the state of the modal.
The modal component should care only about his value and open state and callback on ok
The higher component contain the input logic and pass pther props to modal component.

Maybe this is not the best way, but is the best i could develop with my limited knowledge